# R: R Script that Calculates Student GPA from Letter Grades

Tags: r, statistics

I need help drafting a R script that calculates average GPA of numerous students (designated by sample ID) in a data set.  The GPA should be calculated using the standard 4 point scale (A=4, B=3, C=2, D=1, and F=0). When a student does not have an assigned grade, the assignment does not count towards average GPA.

Here is a sample data set:

```
df <- data.frame(sampleid = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), HW1 = c("A","","B","F","B","A","C"), HW2 = c("A","A","C","","A","D",""), Exam = c("A","A","A","A","A","D","B"))
```

Comment: it would be better to include your expected otput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a named vector to change the values and then take the average with `rowMeans`

```
nm1 <- setNames(4:0, c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'))
rowMeans( `dim<-`(nm1[as.matrix(df[-1])], dim(df[-1])), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 4.000000 4.000000 3.000000 2.000000 3.666667 2.000000 2.500000
```

Comment: That is incredibly short and sweet - good stuff. If I was doing a tidy version my steps would be much longer - pivot the Df long, create a data frame of grades and scores, join to the original df, then group by and mutate with a mean function.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some assumptions about how to handle blanks (ignore in mean calculation) and the scores (is E a possible grade?).

Code is way longer relative to Akrun, though i've doen it step by step with sending the results to screen to make it clear what is happening.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(sampleid = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), HW1 = c("A","","B","F","B","A","C"), HW2 = c("A","A","C","","A","D",""), Exam = c("A","A","A","A","A","D","B"))
df

#Pivot data into long format
df_long <- df %>% pivot_longer(-1,"assessment")
df_long

#Make blank "" into NA so they will be ignored in mean calculation, and make "value" type character
df_long$value <- df_long$value %>% na_if("")
df_long$value <- as.character(df_long$value)
df_long

#make df_key of grades and their scores, "value" is a character to match df_long
df_key <- tibble(
  "value" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),  
  "mark" = c(4,3,2,1,0,0))
df_key

#Join df_key to df
df_long <- full_join(df_long, df_key)
df_long

#Calculate mean by group (student)
results <- df_long %>% group_by(sampleid) %>% summarise(mean_grade=mean(mark, na.rm = TRUE))
results
```